# closest in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to click on `.dropzone` class through jQuery when users click on `.dropzone-upload-btn` element. I have this code but it is not doing anything. Any idea why?

```
<div class="dropzone-wrapper">
  <div class="dropzone"></div>
  <div class="dropzone-upload-btn"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery code (simplified)

```
$('.dropzone-upload-btn').on("click", function() {
  return $(this).closest('.dropzone').click();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closest` looks at the matched element and its ancestors. You probably want `siblings`:

```
$('.dropzone-upload-btn').on("click", function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.dropzone').click();
});
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Of course, if you're 100% sure the `.dropzone` element will come immediately before the `.dropzone-upload-btn` element, then you can use `prev` or `prevAll`:

```
$('.dropzone-upload-btn').on("click", function() {
    return $(this).prev('.dropzone').click();
});
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

`prevAll` can be used if you know the target element will come before the matched one, but not necessarily **immediately** before. `prev` will only look at the *first* **immediate** previous sibling.

The difference between `prevAll` and `siblings` is that `siblings` looks at siblings before **and** after the matched element, while `prevAll` looks only at the siblings before it.